Where is the setting of The Supernaturalist?
The Supernaturalist is a novel by Eoin Colfer set in a dystopian future. When I read it twenty years ago, I'd vaguely assumed it was probably set somewhere in the Americas, but now I wonder if the name "Cosmonaut Hill" implies a setting in the ex-Soviet region of the world. I also recall a mention, from Redwood in the early chapters, of some currency (pesos? dinars?), which might also imply something about the setting.
What can be deduced from the story (or from any extratextual material, if necessary) about the location? Wikipedia says "an unspecified location in the Northern Hemisphere", but I feel sure we can do better than that.
